# How do I to translate this json format into correct format that can be used pandas read_json()

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is first time use stackoverflow to ask question. I have poor English,so if I affend you accidently in word, please don't mind.

I have a json file (access.json),format like:

```
[
{u'IP': u'aaaa1', u'Domain': u'bbbb1', u'Time': u'cccc1', ..... },
{u'IP': u'aaaa2', u'Domain': u'bbbb2', u'Time': u'cccc2', ..... },
{u'IP': u'aaaa3', u'Domain': u'bbbb3', u'Time': u'cccc3', ..... },
{u'IP': u'aaaa4', u'Domain': u'bbbb4', u'Time': u'cccc4', ..... },
{ ....... }, 
{ ....... } 
]
```

When I use:

```
ipython
import pasdas as pd
data = pd.read_json('./access.json')
```

it return:

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

that is the result I want:

```
[out]
       IP    Domain     Time    ...
0   aaaa1     bbbb1    cccc1    ...
1   aaaa2     bbbb2    cccc2    ...
2   aaaa3     bbbb3    cccc3    ...
3   aaaa4     bbbb4    cccc4    ...
...and so on
```

How should I do to achieve this goal? Thank you for answer!

Comment: This is not a valid json file (strings should be encloses in double quotes " rather than single prepended with a u). Are you generating this "json" file?

Comment: TO @Andy Hayden, Yes, I generate this file via someone example.(now I know it is wrong.) Can you teach me how format can be use pandas read_json()? I had tried this [{"IP":"aaaa" ,"Domain":"bbb" ....},{...}...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't valid json which is why `read_json` won't parse it.

```
{u'IP': u'aaaa1', u'Domain': u'bbbb1', u'Time': u'cccc1', ..... },
```

should be

```
{"IP": "aaaa1", "Domain": "bbbb1", "Time": "cccc1", ..... },
```

You *could* smash this (the entire file) with a regular expression to find these, for example:

```
In [11]: line
Out[11]: "{u'IP': u'aaaa1', u'Domain': u'bbbb1', u'Time': u'cccc1'},"

In [12]: re.sub("(?<=[\{ ,])u'|'(?=[:,\}])", '"', line)
Out[12]: '{"IP": "aaaa1", "Domain": "bbbb1", "Time": "cccc1"},'
```

*Note: this will get tripped up by some strings, so use with caution.*

**A better "solution" would be to ensure you had valid json in the first place**... It looks like this has come from python's str/unicode/repr rather than `json.dumps`.

*Note: `json.dumps` produces valid json, so can be read by `read_json`.*

```
In [21]: repr({u'IP': u'aaa'})
Out[21]: "{u'IP': u'aaa'}"

In [22]: json.dumps({u'IP': u'aaa'})
Out[22]: '{"IP": "aaa"}'
```

If someone else created this "json", then complain! It's not json.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a JSON format. It is a list of dictionaries. You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get the actual list from the file and pass it to the [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) constructor:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

with open('./access.log2.json') as f:
    data = literal_eval(f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
```

Output for the example data you've provided:

```
  Domain     IP   Time
0  bbbb1  aaaa1  cccc1
1  bbbb2  aaaa2  cccc2
2  bbbb3  aaaa3  cccc3
3  bbbb4  aaaa4  cccc4
```

Comment: thank you for answer! 
I try this way, it return me message 'killed'.

Comment: If I have a lot of data, is there else way to complete this job?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
pd.read_json("{json_file_name}", orient='records')
```

assuming that the JSON data is in list format as shown in the question.